# How does JavaScript's instanceof operator work?

Tags: javascript, prototype

After creating an inheritance chain with `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype)`, which properties does JavaScript's `instanceof` use to determine that an object is an instance of a particular class?

For example:

```
var Fruit = function() {};

var Banana = function() {};
Banana.prototype = Object.create(Fruit.prototype);

var YellowBanana = function() {};
YellowBanana.prototype = Object.create(Banana.prototype);

console.log((new Fruit) instanceof Fruit); // true
console.log((new Banana) instanceof Fruit); // true
console.log((new YellowBanana) instanceof Banana); // true
console.log((new YellowBanana) instanceof Fruit); // true
```

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionality equivalent to the `instanceof` operator could be implemented in plain Javascript like this:

```
function instance_of(obj, constructor) {
  var o = obj, prot=constructor.prototype;
  while(o != null && o !== Object) {
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
    if(o === prot) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

That uses the ES5 function, [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to access the prototype of a given object instance.  `getPrototypeOf` is supported in all modern browsers, and javascript environments.  Most older browsers relied on the `__proto__` property (now deprecated/discouraged) to provide access to the same information.

Comment: Thanks, that produces the same results as the `instanceof` operator. In this example, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new YellowBanana))) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(YellowBanana.prototype)) === Fruit.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

If we arrange the expression as `object instanceof constructor` then it checks to see if `constructor.prototype` is in the prototype of `object`.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Answer (score 0):

The reason these all return true is because they **all** have the the prototype of the specified function you're checking against

When you do

```
Instance instanceof TheFunction
```

It will look at all the `prototype`'s of `Instance` and check if `TheFunction.prototype` is in there

**From Mozilla:**

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

Answer (score -4):

The prototype, of course. [prototype](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)